# I need to optimaze my code that containt two loops. The code is for calculating a sum of numbers

Tags: python, performance, optimization, sum, mathematical-optimization

I was traying to write a code that calculate the sum of 2*j+i+1 where 0<=j<=i<=n but I wasn't very optimazed
there are my code :

```
def get_sum(n):
    s=0
    for j in range(n+1):
        ss=0
        ss=sum(2*j+i+1 for i in range(j,n+1))
        s+=ss
    return s
```

Write to calculate a a sum of 2*j+i+1 where 0<=j<=i<=n but it wasn't optimazed

Comment: FWIW, `ss=0` is unnecessary.

Answer (score 5):

Before delving into optimizing *the code*, always take a step back and consider *what* the code does. In this case, try to solve the equations with pen and paper, instead of brute-forcing them with a computer.

The value you want, lets call it `S` is defined as

[image]

Compute the inner sum first

[image]

And, finally, substitute and compute the outer sum

[image]

The second to last expression is the fastest one to use, as it uses fewer multiplications (and an "easier" division). If you are unfamiliar with any of the math above, look up the basic summation properties and identities.

And your function is simply

```python
def get_sum(n):
    return (n+1)*(n+2)*(4*n+3)/2
```

Comment: I'm familiar with that, but I was thinking if there any way to optimaze the for loop, anyways thank you that could help me to think diffrently next time.

Answer (score 2):

This is really just a math question:

```
def get_sum2(n):
    return (4*n*n*n + 15*n*n + 17*n + 6)/6
```

As you mentioned that you want to simplify the code:

```
sum([2*j+i+1 for i in range(n+1) for j in range(i+1)])
```

Comment: How did you figure that out? I never learned this in school.

Comment: Why `n*n*n` and `n*n` instead of `n**3` and `n**2`?

Comment: All you need is the formula for sum(i) and sum(i^2). As for `n*n` it makes no difference

Comment: Ah, OK. I just found that myself [here on Math SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1899502/652782). Thanks!

Comment: @ZLi did you account for the fact that the inner sum is from `j` to `n`, not `1` to `n`? (It's not obvious, and I'm clearly too lazy to check myself :) )

Comment: @chepner Yeah, and I verified the numerical results as well